# undefinedStepdefinitionexception - Matching multiple phrases cucumber step definition

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

Good day
I have recently converting from cucumber-java8 to cucumber-java and was facing issue with Regular expression in step definition.

Cucumber is not identifying the steps which we have clubbed under one step definition.

Example:

```
@Given(" client (created)/(requests to create) application for code {string}")
public void client_createdrequests_to_create_application_for_code_string(String code) {
// code for steps
}
```

Feature file 1:

`client created application for code 200`

Feature file 2:

`client requests to create application for code 201`

I have tried to add escape characters for the braces (, ) but still was facing same issue

```
@Given(" client \\(created)/\\(requests to create) application for code {string}")
public void client_createdrequests_to_create_application_for_code_string(String code) {
// code for steps
}
```

Can you let me know what should be done for this case to make cucumber identify it? Along with escaping the expressions of cucumber

New cucumber-java version is 7.12.1
cucumber-gherkin 7.13.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber uses regex to match the steps to the definitions. The easy way to capture anything that matches a pattern is to use `(.*)`:

```
@Given(" client (.*) application for code {string}")
public void client_createdrequests_to_create_application_for_code_string(String code) {
    // code for steps
}
```

If you specifically want to match those words and nothing else, you can use `|` (OR):

```
@Given(" client (created|requests to create) application for code {string}")
public void client_createdrequests_to_create_application_for_code_string(String code) {
    // code for steps
}
```

For more info, look at regex expressions.